# C++: #included <fstream> but cannot use getline?

Tags: c++, string, getline

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
.
.
.

void function() {
    ofstream inputFile;
    .
    .
    .
    inputFile.getline (inputFile, inputField1, ",");
}
```

For some reason I can't figure out, compiling this using g++ returns

```
error: ‘struct std::ofstream’ has no member named ‘getline’
```

Also, as a side note, it also generates errors

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’
error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘size_t*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’
```

But I think I got the parameters the wrong way round or something.

Can anyone help shed any light?

Comment: There seem to be multiple issues: `ofstream` used for input, you seem to be trying to read into a `std::string` (and thus the member function `getline` in `istream` will not work either...) Google for `getline` and locate the free function that takes a `std::string`

Answer (score 3):

There are two getline functions which take delimiters in c++.

One is in ifstream:

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim);
```

The other is in string:

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
```

It seems from your example that you are anticipating the usage of the one from string.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream inputFile;
  string inputField1;

  inputFile.open("hi.txt");

  getline(inputFile, inputField1, ',');

  cout << "String is " << inputField1 << endl;

  int field1;
  stringstream ss;
  ss << inputField1;
  ss >> field1;

  cout << "Integer is " << field1 << endl;

  inputFile.close();

}
```

Comment: The type of inputField1 in my program is int. Does this work the same way?

Comment: How do you specify from which of ifstream or string you want to use?

Comment: The program above reads the first field into a string. To convert it to an integer use a stringstream. To use the getline from ifstream, see Carl Norum's code below. Notice it uses inputFile.getline(), rather than just getline(). And the type of the fields it expects are different. The getline from string reads to a string, which is dynamically allocated. This is useful if you don't know in advance the maximum length of the field you are reading. The ifstream getline is only able to read up to the preallocated size of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

An ofstream is an output file stream.  You need an ifstream.

Answer (score 1):

An [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) is an output stream, hence a `getline`method doesn't make sense. Maybe you need [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

Answer (score 1):

An `ofstream` is an *output* stream, so it doesn't have any input methods.  You probably want `ifstream`:

```
void function() {
    ifstream inputFile("somefilename");
    char buf[SOME_SIZE];
    inputFile.getline (buf, sizeof buf, ',');
}
```